# Django: Access model field with two keys in template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am a bit lost. It is been a while since I did some Django and I almost forgot everything about querysets and template. The app is a questionaire for comparing different vendors - hence their products. It is a questionaire with a scoring (best match) to each product.

I want to access a specific element in a for loop which has two foreign keys to other classes. Here my model:

**Model:**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    questionText = models.CharField(max_length=500)

class Vendor(models.Model):
    vendorName = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

class Scoring(models.Model):        
    score = models.IntegerField(default='0', blank=True)
    questionScoreForKey = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, related_name='scorequestion', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    vendorForKey = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, null=True, related_name='scorevendor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    vendors = Vendor.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'compare/index.html', {'questions': questions, 'vendors': vendors})
```

**Template**

```
{% for ask in questions %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ ask.questionText }}  </td>
    {% for vend in vendors %}
    <td id="Vendor_{{ ask.pk }}_{{ vend.pk }}" style> {{ HERE THE SCORE OF THE QUESTION AND VENDOR  }}  </td> 
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Both keys are existing but I have no clue how to access the score of e. g. the first question for the first vendors. Any hint appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reverse query the scores. Since you've defined related names in your models, you can use them.

Note that a reverse query gives you a manager object. The `all` method returns a queryset with all objects matching the reverse query (you defined a one-to-many relationship, one question/vendor can have many scores). Then further filter the queryset to get the instance you need (e.g. `first`).

```
{{vendor.scorevendor.all.first.score}}
```

Comment: stackoverflow is full of heros. You are mine. Thank you! One comment: the first line is the solution - getting the score of the question of the specific vendor. But for the number we need to point to the field `score`. Hence `{{vendor.scorevendor.all.first.score}}` Otherwise we have only the object. The second line only points to the first score of the question of the current ID. Can you change that and I will accept your answer.